# Performance aspect of mis-aligned arrays from JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, memory-alignment

When passing two arrays from java to c++ through JNI, there are three obstacles against using c++ intrinsics(or asm-inline) to boost performance.

1)JNI calling has an overhead(as expected, 20 cycles to 100 cycles)

2)Arrays are passed as mis-aligned(needed 32B or 16B alignement) so one needs to shift whole two arrays to make them aligned then in the end shift-back to old position.

3)Creating a new array to send the results to java(example: vector multiplication C=A*B) If we supply an array from java, it will be mis-aligned too! So we need to create a new aligned array in c++ which slows down the whole process.

Rather than shifting two arrays, we can make a single bigger array to concatenate two arrays but that would be slow too.

What is the point of using JNI for performance if we can use only (less-data,more-compute) structs?

--Using pure c++(no intrinsic) in JNI makes just %10-%20 faster then pure java.

--Using intrinsics increased the multiplications/s by %70 but slow array copying is still in effect. Only %50 chance that java moves its arrays into a 32B aligned position.

--Using `GetPrimitiveArrayCritical` instead of `GetArrayElements()` gave another %250 performance to the dot-product of big vectors(256k elements). Which must be the result of shutting gc-down for the moment of JNI work and non-copy-accessing.

--Using Direct Byte Buffer instead of primitive arrays is %40(5x-6x on top of pure java) faster on my machine. Also lets me choose a custom offset in it with help of native-address chooser to make it 32B aligned. So we can have 32B aligned sub-set of a direct buffer(in "C" space) but not a primitive array.

-- Dividing a big buffer into 8 parts and into 8 java threads, made the calculation another %40 faster compared to single directbytebuffer(This may be close to limit of my ram since I only do a single multiplication per element)

Total speed ratio of latest case vs java's loop-unrolled multiplication for single thread was nearly 6x, after I applied multithreading it increased to 8x(not much because of memory bandwidth, not the compute limit) for this particular dot-product.

What can you add to overcome three difficulties above?

**How can we pass 32B-aligned arrays from java to c++ through JNI?**

Comment: Is using NIO Buffers an option for you?

Comment: Can they made as aligned as wanted?

Comment: I'm new to jni never used them personaly but docs says they can.

Comment: Can you give any link please?

Comment: http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/jni-14.html#NewDirectByteBuffer

Comment: @user629926 The link you gave seems to be suitable for c++ or JNI-originated projects. Mine is centered around jvm so that is some slowish in java. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Here is a relevant bug report: http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6661301 . I am surprised to hear about this -- you'd think they'd have done this correctly in the first place.

Comment: It seems arrays are only optimized for sse, not avx. This means I can skip first 16 bytes of arrays from java, using aligned access then doing that 16 bytes by serial computing. Will try in an hour.

Comment: @user629926 Thank you, buffer performance is awesome.